# Не работает FOSUserBundle

Tags: framework, symfony3

```
InvalidConfigurationException in VariableNode.php line 88.
The path "fos_user.from_email.address" cannot contain an empty value, but got null.
```

в symfony3 при установке fOSUserBundle. Не знаю в чем проблема

Answer (score 3):

Надо добавить в `config.yml` для `fos_user`:

```
# ...
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\Admin
    # ...
    from_email:
        address: you@example.com
        sender_name: You
# ...
```

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-5-configure-the-fosuserbundle